# Understand AUCs of different models

Tags: roc, auc, confusion-matrix

I'm testing two models against each other:

1. provides an AUC of 93,94 % with TP = 99,9 %, TN = 0 %, FP = 100 % and FN = 0.1 %.
2. provides an AUC of 92,78 % with TP = 98,8 %, a TN = 30,6 %, FP = 69,4 % and FN = 1,2 %.

How can model 2) have a lower AUC while the TN is much higher?
There are 1442 observations in total, while around 1300 belong to one class and the other 142 to the other.

To be precise: The model is the same but for the one model I don't modify the data while for the second model I split the serial number of devices into several blocks.
So the models and data are, in principle, the same.

Comment: It's a bit hard to compare a global measure like ROC with one at a single threshold like the true negative rate. Have you considered you may not be using an optimal threshold?

Comment: Isn't AUC considering "all" thresholds?

Comment: Yes exactly. And your measure of TN exactly one. There are several related questions on this site, I just can't find a good one right now.